# Is it against the rules to fly in the NBA?

Tags: rules, nba

If someone were to miraculously develop the super power to fly (say they could hover up to 1000 feet and swiftly move in three dimensions) would any rules as currently defined by the NBA prevent the use of this power during play?

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. [A previous meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/) suggests we should not have a problem with this question, though I would advise potential answerers to focus purely on the rules rather than speculate on effects this would have.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe flying would break any specific rules in the NBA (or FIBA) rulebook - but that's not really the same as saying "flying is legal in the NBA" as the governing body for a sport (any sport) isn't going to waste its time writing explicit rules to cover situations which can "never" occur.

If we ever got to a state where flying was a reasonable possibility, something would be done to the basketball rules to regulate it. For example, the rules regulate goaltending, something which is a realistic possibility for humans today.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I probably didn’t explain the intention of my question well enough. It wasn’t about whether there was some rule that had been created on the off-chance someone developed superpowers, but more about whether there was some pre-existing rule that just happened to forbid that kind of movement as a side-effect of the actual intent of the rule. Say, a rule about traveling that restricts how you can move while in possession of the ball, etc.